# Browser Extension to count and show data downloaded

Tags: browser, firefox-extensions, google-chrome-extensions, data-transfer

Is there a browser extension to show the amount of data downloaded, and to group it by each website?

For example:

- Total Data Download 50MB.
- Youtube.com 30MB
- Google.com 20MB

Answer (score 0):

Not a browser extension and not grouping by website, but useful to get overall stats (per day etc.):

[NetMeter for Windows](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Network-Tools/Bandwidth-Tools/NetMeter.shtml)

Actually there's source code available on the [author's site](http://www.metal-machine.de/readerror/index.php?action=tpmod;dl=item24) so someone can add new feature but I don't know how difficult it would be to add a feature of grouping by site.

To get the stats, right click in the system tray and choose "Totals".